# browserify bs58 library after npm install

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, radix

I'm attempting to browserify the `bs58` module following [these instructions](http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/misc/bs58/):

```
npm install --save bs58

npm install -g browserify

browserify < /mypath/lib/bs58.js > /mypath/lib/bs85.bundle.js
```

Then in my html + js file I use:

As I understand it this should give me a bs58 object to access the `encode` and `decode` functions. However, I get `ReferenceError: bs58 is not defined` on attempting usage.

Looking at the browserified code looks like:

```
(function(){function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s}return e})()({},{},[]);
```

This doesn't contain the word `encode` as I might expect.

I'm not 100% certain the module installed correctly, but the [demo examples](http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/misc/bs58/) seem to run ok in node (after `require bs58`).

A few questions have come up whilst attempting to debug this:

**1. How do I check whether the bs58 module has been correctly browserified?**

**2. Where should the `lib/bs58.js` be located by default?**

**3. How should I access the `encode` and `decode` bs58 functions in the browser?**

**4. Are there any alternatives for base58 encoding/decoding in the browser?**

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by using the command:

```
browserify /mypath/lib/bs58.js -o /mypath/lib/bs85.bundle.js
```

in place of

```
browserify < /mypath/lib/bs58.js > /mypath/lib/bs85.bundle.js
```

Comment: Where does bs58.js come from in the first place? After I ran "npm install --save bs58" I don't have that. I only have node_modules/bs58/index.js that points to a base-x dependency.